# Saving steam session for a long time

Tags: steam-web-api

I've added to my website [this](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication/) steam login, made the cookies to last for a year but after sometime after logging in it automatically logs me out I would like how to make the session to be longer.

Is it a problem in cookies or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked it locally and found that if you increase the value of `session.gc_maxlifetim` it would increase the life of the cookies, the time until the cookies deleted.